# How do i create a html checklist form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i am struggling to create checklist form

How do i create a html checklist form

For example :-

Drop down menu, where i can choose from suppliers,

When i choose a specific supplier, it should load the data of the supplier:

'Do we pay in advance?' and a 'Input Radio' button.
If, and only if, this button is clicked it should load some more options:

```
option1:    - 'Is invoice more than than 100 dollars?' and a 'Input Radio' button.
If, and only if, this button is clicked it should load some more options:
    'Add special terms' followed by a 'Input(checkbox)'
    'Inform supplier' followed by a 'Input(checkbox)


option2:    - 'Special attention required?' and a 'Input Radio' button.
If, and only if, this button is clicked it should load some more options:
    'special terms applied' followed by a 'Input(checkbox)'
    'supplier contacted by phone' followed by a 'Input(checkbox)'
    'email sent to supplier' followed by a 'Input(checkbox)'

option3:    'Invoice created' followed by a 'Input(checkbox)'
```

In the bottom there should be a 'submit' button. When i click on it, it should chekc if all checkboxes have been checked.

please help ... Thanks

Comment: We do not code for you - we help you improve your code or find a flaw in your code. But in all cases, you need to do your work first.

Answer (score -1):

A straightforward way to do this is to dynamically render the content as events occur using events on the page.  You can build event listeners with native document listeners or JQuery.  Going with JQuery, you can define your first drop down, which is a list of suppliers, with an identifier, say, id="supplier", and invoke a function that occurs when a select event happens on the supplier box that inserts the next control, populated with the proper data, on the page.

The JQuery documentation will be particularly helpful here.  Unfortunately this question is very broad and the answer will depend on the structure of your page, if you're using a client side framework, etc. etc, but it sounds to me like what you're looking for is an event driven form.  I hope this points you in the right direction.